# Don't meet the condition in if() but it dosen't show the MessageBox.show(""); Everything else works just fine

Tags: c#, winforms, oledbconnection, login-page

```
public partial class FormLogin : Form
{
    private OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
    //private bool CheckUserName = false;

    public FormLogin()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Class\This Semester\C#\Code\Access Login App\Database1.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            DBCheckLabel.Text = "Connected";
            connection.Close();
        } catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error:" + ex);
        }
    }

    private void log_in_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            connection.Open();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "select * from acctbl where Username=" + txt_bx_Username.Text + "and Password ='" + txt_bx_Password.Text + "';";
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string username = reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("UserName")).ToString();
                string password = reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("Password")).ToString();

                if (username.Equals(txt_bx_Username.Text))
                {
                    if (password.Equals(txt_bx_Password.Text))
                    {
                        this.Hide();
                        FormProfile f1 = new FormProfile();
                        f1.Show();
                    }
                    else
                        MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Pass");            
                }
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Username");
            }

            reader.Close();
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex);
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for Login Page. It goes to next from if the user name and password is correct but don't show message in else block if user name or password not matched.

```
private void log_in_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            connection.Open();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "select `UserName`, `Password` from acctbl;";
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string username = reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("UserName")).ToString();
                string password = reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("Password")).ToString();


                if (username.Equals(txt_bx_Username.Text))
                {

                    if (password.Equals(txt_bx_Password.Text))
                    {
                        this.Hide();
                        FormProfile f1 = new FormProfile();
                        f1.Show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Pass");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Username");
                }
            }



            reader.Close();
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception exbtn)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error" + exbtn);
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

After got help from this site I coded it right as below. Get all value from Database record and check if it match with entered Username then check if match with recorded password. IF not then it shows the message box. Now it works fine.

Comment: Nobody is going to bother debugging a *screenshot*. Paste your code into the question body, while making sure that it constitutes a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem you're facing. While you're at it, read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for instructions on how to ask a good question.

Comment: Please add your code as text in your question.

Comment: I don't know where to start... SQL-injection, plain text passwords, separate error message for wrong username and password... this code is a feast of security problems.

Comment: Your code suffers from SQL injection. You're storing passwords in the database. If this is for a large audience, you'll certainly be in TV some time in the future.

Comment: oh, and the simple answer to your question: if username or password are incorrect, `while reader.Read()` never executes because no record is returned from the database.

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  Based on that screenshot, you need lots of help and will want to be able to ask *good* questions to get good answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your code is dangerous.**

There are several security issues with it.

The reason your code does not work is quite simple: you try to read a record from the database with the given username and password. If the username or password is incorrect, you do not retrieve any record, so `while(reader.Read())` never executes.

If you *do* retrieve a record, it is utterly useless to compare username and password, they will *always match* because you just read them from the database.

Fix your SQL-injection issue, store password hashes instead of plain text passwords and use a different algorithm to check:

Either try to read a records from your database with the given username and *hashed* password and return an error if no record is found, or read a record from the database with only the username an check the retrieved password hash.

In either case, simply return a generic error message if anything is wrong. Do not give out information about it being the username or the password that is wrong. Just a simple "incorrect username or password" is enough.